# Vue, Jest. Падает тест вызова метода при клике

Tags: javascript, vue.js, юнит-тесты, jest

Начал изучать тему unit тестирования Vue компонентов. Использую Jest.

Появился затык с одни тестом, никак не могу понять в чем дело.

Хочу протестировать вызов функции в компоненте, при клике на определенный элемент.

```html
<template>
  <li 
  class="message" 
  style="margin-top: 10px"
  @click="handleClick"
  >
    {{ message }}
  </li>
</template>
```

При прямом вызове функции тест срабатывает, но при клике - падает, так как функция почему то не вызывается. При этом во время реального клика - все ок.

```js
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Message from "@/components/Message.vue";

describe("Message.test.js", () => {
    let wrapper;
    const createWrapper = propsData => mount(Message, { propsData });
    
    describe("Events", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            wrapper = createWrapper({ message: "Cat" });
        });
//Работает -функция вызывается напрямую
    it("calls handleClick", () => {
            const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'handleClick');
            wrapper.vm.handleClick();
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
        //Падает
         it("calls handleClick when click on message", () => {
            const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'handleClick');
            expect(wrapper.contains('.message')).toBe(true);

            wrapper.find('.message').trigger('click');
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        })
   });
});
```

Добавил вывод в консоль при вызове метода - вижу, что во время тестирования с кликом, метод вызывается. Не могу понять, почему тест падает

Answer (score 0):

Теперь работает:

```js
 
 it('calls handleClick when click on message', () => {
            const handleClick = jest.fn()
            wrapper.setMethods({ handleClick })
            const el = wrapper.find('.message').trigger('click')
            expect(handleClick).toBeCalled()
        })
//Используем stub
        it('triggers a message-clicked event when a handleClick method is called', () => {
            const stub = jest.fn()
            wrapper.vm.$on('message-clicked', stub)
            wrapper.vm.handleClick()
            expect(stub).toBeCalledWith('Cat')
        })
```